# Sending static props to component via selector, best practice

Tags: react-native, redux

I sometimes have need to send static props to a component, but the data actually comes from my Redux store. I.e. I need a access to **state** to fetch the data.

With static, I mean that this data won't change during the life of the component, so I don't want to select it from the store on each render.

#### This is how I solved it at first (the mapStateToProps part):

```
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    journalItemType: selectJournalItemType(state, ownProps.journalItemTypeId)
  })
```

The component gets a *JournalItemTypeId* and the mapStateToProps looks it up in the store and sends the journalItemType to the component. JournalItemType is static metadata and won't change very often, and certainly not during the life of the component.

```
static propTypes = {
  journalItemType: ImmutablePropTypes.map.isRequired,
}
```

The problem with this is that I call the selector at each render. Not a big performance hit, but feels wrong anyway.

#### So, I changed to this:

```
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    getJournalItemType: () => selectJournalItemType(state, ownProps.journalItemTypeId)
  })
```

The first thing I do in the components constructor is to call getJournalItemType and store the result in the local state. This way the selector is only called once.

```
static propTypes = {
  getJournalItemType: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    journalItemType: props.getJournalItemType()
  }
}
```

#### Question:

Is this the right way to do this?

Another way would be to let the component know about **state** so the component could call the selector itself. But I think it's cleaner to keep the state out of the component.

I could also call the selector and fetch the static data earlier in the call chain, but I don't have **state** naturally available there either.

#### Clarification:

Why would I store *JournalItemTypes* in the Redux store if it is static data? All of the apps metadata is in my redux store so it can be easily refreshed from the server. By keeping it in Redux I can treat metadata in the same way as all other data in my synchronisation sagas.

#### Added clarification after Mika's answer

I need to use the local state because the component is a quite complex input form with all sorts of inputs (input fields, camera, qr-reader, live updated SVG sketch based on input).

A JournalItem in my app is "all or nothing". I.e. if every required field is filled in the user is allowed to save the item. My store is persisted to disk, so I don't want to hit the store more often than needed. So the JournalItem-object (actually an Immutable.map) lives in state until it's ready to be saved.

My selectors are memoized with reselect. This makes my first solution even less impacting on performance. But it still feels wrong.

The component gets updated via props due to other events, so it's re-rendered now and then.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options here:

#### Option 1: the original way

This is the most basic and most 'Redux' way of doing it. If your `selectJournalItemType` function is moderately light, your app won't suffer much of a performance hit as `mapStateToProps` is only called when the store is updated [according to react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

#### Option 2: the constructor

It is generally recommended to avoid using the Component's state with Redux. Sometimes it is necessary (for example forms with inputs) but in this case it can, and in my opinion should, be avoided.

#### Option 3: optimizing option 1

If your function is computationally expensive, there are at least a few ways to optimize the original solution.

In my opinion one of the simpler ones is [optimizing the react-redux `connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#optimizing-connect-when-optionspure-is-true). Short example:

```
const options = {
  pure: true, // True by default
  areStatesEqual: (prev, next) => {
    // You could do some meaningful comparison between the prev and next states
    return false;
  }
};

export default ContainerComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
  options
)(PresentationalComponent);
```

Another possibility is to create a [memoized function using Reselect](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)

Comment: Thanks Mika. I have added some more clarifications to my original post. The options object seems interesting. I didn't know that connect() could take a fourth parameter. What's the difference between shouldComponentUpdate() and areStatesEqual()?

Comment: Nitpick: it is _absolutely fine_ to use component state in a Redux application as needed.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state .

Comment: @Michael - `shouldComponentUpdate()` is a Component lifespan method, meaning it's fired when the component receives new props or state is changed. `areStatesEqual()` evaluates whether `mapStateToProps` needs to execute at all (thus deciding whether new props are passed to the component). Regarding your worries about re-renders: that's the part React is really good at. I wouldn't worry about it.
@markerikson - very true, and in some cases you have to use component state. I've just found the data and state easier to manage when using as much Redux state as reasonable.